# java andorid create file when connect divece to pc , a file is not exist

Tags: java, android

So when I create a file on my application my device see this file but when I connected a device to my computer I go to this path I don't see this file. I see this file when I copy this file to diffrent folder (in my device) or restart device . What I should to do to have this file and not do it this ?

This is how I save this file :

```
  Serializer serializer = new Persister();
//                  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "yourFolder";
//
//                  File folder = new File(path);
                    File file1 = new File(folder, "news222.xml");

                    try {
                        serializer.write(LFRFIDActivity.root, file1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Try to post an example (and maybe a schema) so we can understand precisely in which cases you can or cannot see a file.

Comment: that is a common situation. as Android device is connected in MTP mode, it takes some time for the new files to be indexed by MTP. You can for example just wait for some time, or reboot your Android device. AFAIK you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Nathan I edit my post

Comment: @VladMatvienko ok but can I do something programically to see this file and not rebot a device ?

Comment: `AFAIK you can't do anything about it`

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka If I understand correctly: creting a file in your remote device doesn't wo(rk, but moving a file in it works?

Comment: @Nathan when I move a file or copy this file it works ...

Comment: @VladMatvienko TO said this situation doesn't happen when he's copying a file, so that feels weird.

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka you can try creating the file on your local disk at first **then** copy it on your device.

Comment: @Nathan when I create a file onmy computer and copy to device I see this file

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka When you say "I see", you mean it appears on your device explorer or you can access it from your java program?

Comment: @Nathan I have acces in my android java programm and see in explorer

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka Then please add this in your question (extended discussion in comments otherwise). Precise when you can and cannot access your files in your java program. As far as we know, it could be created instantly on your device, but not appear instantly yin your explorer because it doesn't constantly probe your device, whereas copying it will force an update (oyur OS know that the state was modified).

Comment: My android-4.4 device has the same problem: it needs some time (15 minutes) before the usb-file-server sees the newly createded file to make it available via usb on the pc side.

Comment: @k3b I wait 1 hour and I don't see this file , when I rebot a device I see this file ...

Answer (score 0):

I did this after create a file and it works :

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
```

Comment: Interesting to see that the delay comes from the media scanner/media database. Note you should check this for different android-versions. i know that android before versoin 4.4 always do a full media scan with this call because MediaScannerConnection.scanFile was not implemented for a single file. (at least not on my own android-4.2 device). newer androids may do this on their own when ever there is a file change. Wich android version are you using?

Comment: My device use a android 5.0